# How to add external login in .net web api 2?

Tags: social-networking, asp.net-web-api, facebook-login

I'm trying to add external login with template from MVC5, Web API2 with method

```
Task<IHttpActionResult> AddExternalLogin(AddExternalLoginDTO model)
```

The method need only one parameter ExternalAccessToken - token from FB, Google, ...

But ticket for some user data is still null

```
AuthenticationTicket ticket = AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(model.ExternalAccessToken);
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Ever find an approach for this?