# How to add external login to existing account Identity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to add external login (facebook/twitter) to existing account using method **api/Account/AddExternalLogin** from WebAPI2 template, but method always returns 500 status because this ticket is null:

```
AuthenticationTicket ticket = AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(model.ExternalAccessToken);
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

At first I call **api/Account/ExternalLogin** then **api/Account/RegisterExternal**. These methods create account add link it to external login.

Then I login with another service, get access token and send it as param to   **api/Account/ExternalLogin**

Comment: Found same question without answers :( [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782969/how-to-add-external-login-in-net-web-api-2)

Comment: Ever find an approach for this?

Comment: @Greg no. I didn't find solution so I did my own account system.